# ¿Es posible usar un switch con input de usuario?

Tags: c++, c, dev-c++

Hola tengo un problema al tratar de ejecutar esta pequeña parte de codigo:

```
int costo;
cout << "\nDigite el costo de la unidad...\n"
     << endl;

cin >> costo;

switch (costo)
{
case (costo <= 3000):
    tipo = 'A';
    porcentaje_utilidad = 0.5;
    break;
case (costo > 3000 && costo <= 6000):
    tipo = 'B';
    porcentaje_utilidad = 0.4;
case (costo > 6000):
    tipo = 'C';
    porcentaje_utilidad = 0.3;
default:
    break;
}
```

VS code me advierte enseguida del siguiente error: "la expresión debe tener un valor constante", y no me deja compilar, investigando me di cuenta que los switch statements no pueden usarse con variables sino con constantes, pero como es un input del usuario no puede ser una constante, hay alguna forma de realizar el switch con el input del usuario o forzosamente tengo que usar "if else"?

Comment: Si, tienes que usar `if else`. El `switch` va a base de distintos valores de la variable que le des, no a base de condiciones respecto a esa variable. Para condiciones, usa `if`.

Comment: Sí se puede. Lo que no se puede es decirle "haz switch sobre costo pero evalúame expresiones booleanas que no tienen relación con posibles valores de costo. Puedes revisar un case (3000) o un case(6000), pero no puedes ejecutar una evaluación de una expresión lógica. Usa if-else como te indicaron

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus respuestas, me quedo más claro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La razón no es como tal que estás usando el input del usuario. Lo que pasa es que tú quieres evaluar una condición en el switch y el switch-case (en C++) lo puedes ver cómo que comparas el valor del `case` contra el valor del `switch`, no sirve para evaluar condiciones.

Cómo ya comentaron algunas personas, ocupas usar un `if-else`